# Нет запятой перед как. Обстоятельственное значение сравнительного оборота

Tags: пунктуация, как, сравнительный-оборот, обстоятельство

Очень сложно со сравнительными оборотами, примыкающими к глаголам. Пытаюсь выяснить, когда запятая не нужна. Понятно, что если устойчивые выражение "устал как проклятый", "голодный как волк" и т.д. Но если это обычные сравнения со значением обстоятельства, что тогда? Грамота [говорит](http://www.gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_183), что только замена однословным обстоятельством ("как змея" — "по-змеиному") является аргументом. Лопатин считает так же, приводит пример со львами: "как львы"— "по-львиному". Но посмотрим, например, на предложение:

> Он вспотел(,) как боров

Я бы здесь запятую не ставил, хотя и не заменишь конструкцию одним словом (по-боровьи? — нет). И что делать в таких случаях?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Оборот желательно обособить: Он вспотел, **как боров.**

Сравнить: Этот Санта вспотел, **как боров.** Я потею, **как боров**.

Другие примеры: Бальзак сидел в старом халате, задыхающийся, как боров. [К. Г. Паустовский. Золотая роза (1955)] Лежишь, как боров, ни о чем не думаешь, только жри, спи да на процедуры ходи. [Виктор Некрасов.

Как видно из примеров, сравнение с боровом используется в разных ситуациях, поэтому значения "по-боровьи" здесь нет. **Это именно сравнительный оборот**: человек потеет, лежит, задыхается, как потеет, лежит, задыхается боров.

**2) Пример со змеёй.**

Тропинка извивалась **как змея.** Тропинка, **как змея**, извивалась между деревьями. В обоих случаях возможна замена "по-змеиному", оборот синонимичен наречию, но это проверка в данном случае не даёт результата.

Другие примеры: След, как будто пьяный, вьется, **как змея**. Стальная стружка вьется, **как змея.** По снегу веревка вьется, **как змея**.

Хотя сравнительный оборот по значению равен наречию (по-змеиному), но его обособление   зависит от его позиции, от распространенности и структуры предложения, от желания автора выделить оборот и т. д.

**А чем оборот со значением наречия принципиально отличается от наречия?** Одиночное наречие тоже может быть обособлено, например: Они, **с выставки**, уехали в Крым (М. Г.). В ней было, **в этот момент**, какое-то сходство с Филиппом (Фед.).  Но у оборота, имеющего союз, таких шансов больше, поэтому обособляется он чаще, чем обычное наречие.